# How to use the CORS npm module

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I have set up a very basic example to get the cors module working so that I can make an axios call from a react front end to an express js server.

React front end

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

function App() {

  const callTest = () =>{
    console.log("test called")
    Axios.get('http://localhost/5000/testCall')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p>Welcome to the CORS test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button onClick={() => callTest()}>Click to run test function</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Express node server

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())

const port = 5000

app.get('/testCall', (req,res) =>{
    console.log("test call function has been called!!")
    res.send("Hello from the node server")
})

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    console.log("this was called")
})

app.listen(port, (req,res) =>{
    console.log("app is running on port " + port)
})
```

However I am getting the following error in my browser.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/5000/testCall. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Anybody got any ideas as to what i'm missing?

Comment: You made a typo. In your client side code you put `/5000` instead of `:5000`, so the request went to the wrong server and you got a 404 error instead of a page where the cors module was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.
I got around the issued by using a proxy in the package.json file within the react application

By adding
"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"

Comment: That didn't get the CORS module working. It bypassed the need for CORS permission by making the request same origin.